# Some errors on "dcases" environment in "align"

Tags: align, cases

Before start, I gave some newcommands below.

```
\newcommand{\eqal}[1]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\begin{dcases*}#1\end{dcases*}}
```

The code below works very well.

```
\begin{document}
\section{Question}
1) $E_{1x}E_{1y}\neq 0$
\eqal{
    \case{
        \text{partially longitudinal} \quad (E_{1x} \neq 0) \\
        \text{partially transverse} \quad (E_{1y} \neq 0)
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

However, after adding "&", it shows some errors,

"Missing $ inserted }", and "Extra }, or forgotten $. }".

I could not find the reason why. What is the problem in here?

```
\begin{document}
\section{Question}
1) $E_{1x}E_{1y}\neq 0$
\eqal{
    \case{
        \text{partially longitudinal} \quad & (E_{1x} \neq 0) \\
        \text{partially transverse} \quad & (E_{1y} \neq 0)
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should ask yourself whether this syntax is really better than having explicit `align` and `dcases` environments. My opinion is that it isn't.

Comment: Ah... your right. 'newcommand' is employed to save time, because i used 'begin{align}' and 'end{align}' statement to write equations and texts were written outside the statement. I realized it was needless. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `dcases` environment. It has the following syntax:

```
\begin{dcases*}
  <case 1> & <condition 1> \\
  <case 2> & <condition 2> \\
  ...
\end{dcases*}
```

The above syntax *assumes* `<case X>` is set in math mode, while `<condition X>` is set in *text* mode, as can be seen from the following minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{dcases*}
    A & if $x < 0$ \\
    B & if $x \geq 0$
  \end{dcases*}
\]

\end{document}
```

Without the use of `&`, there is no `<condition>` text, or only a `<case>` is assumed, which is set in math mode. As soon as you use `&` you separate the input into a `<case>` and `<condition>`.

In your case, this separation puts the `<condition>` in text mode, where you cannot use subscripts *without* math mode (in `E_{1x} \neq 0`). Either set the `<condition>` in math mode, or swap them, since that seems also plausible without knowing the context:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\eqal}[1]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\begin{dcases*}#1\end{dcases*}}

\begin{document}

\eqal{
  \case{
    (E_{1x} \neq 0) & \text{partially longitudinal} \\
    (E_{1y} \neq 0) & \text{partially transverse}
  } \\
  \case{
    \text{partially longitudinal} & $(E_{1x} \neq 0)$ \\
    \text{partially transverse}   & $(E_{1y} \neq 0)$
  }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your explanation was really instructive!! Suited examples gave big help. Thank you;